# jquery - variable nth-child?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hey. I want to pass a variable as an argument into an nth-child selector.
This doesn't work:

```
var position = 5;

$("#daddy > div:nth-child(position)").animate({
    opacity: 0.01,
}, 500);​
```

Is it possible though?
Cheers, Jack

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try:

```
var position = 5;

$("#daddy > div:nth-child(" + position + ")").animate({
    opacity: 0.01,
}, 500);​
```

Comment: This just saved me! Can someone explain why this works? I don't get the relevance of the + symbols...

Comment: In case someone else stumbles across this old question and has the same question as Cordial - it's because the CSS selector "#daddy > div: ..." is a string. +, in this context, concatenates two strings together.

Answer (score 6):

You need quoting:

```
var position = 5;

$("#daddy > div:nth-child(" + position + ")").animate({
   opacity: 0.01,
}, 500);​
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
var position = 5;

$("#daddy > div:nth-child(" + position + ")").animate({
    opacity: 0.01,
}, 500);​
```